# Hard to explain; how to get id of category post (explanation inside)

Tags: wordpress

I have category called "people". Each new person I add to this category should have a number that identifies them; I'm *not* looking for the **post ID** because this just gives me the number of the post instead of the number of that specific category's post, e.g. 318 instead of 1.

Here's an example of what I need:

- Nr: 1  Name: Jason
- Nr: 2  Name: Chris
- Nr: 3  Name: Bobby Brown

Let me know if this is clear for you guys or if you need a more thorough explanation,

Comment: What should happen if Nr. 2 is removed? Nr: 3 should become Nr: 2?

Comment: No. People will not be deleted, only updated perhaps so my deletion statement is void. I've just removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to use options to keep track of the running number and post meta data to keep the number of a post.